# Access for-loop index variable from attached for-loop

Tags: c, for-loop, variables

I have this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < var; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j < var2; j++)
    // something which using j variable
```

Can I use `i` variable from first loop instead `var2` variable?

Comment: Are you sure of `i++` in second `for` loop or it's a typo and you mean `j++`?

Comment: Yes, I mean `j++`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a quick note: if your code used brackets{} then the scope of the variables lives within the brackets boundaries.  Wihtout the brackets in c your loop lives until the next semi colon (in other words one line of code)

```
for (int i = 0; i < var; i++) {
   // i can use i here but not j
   for (int j = 0; j < i; i++) {
   // something which using j variable
   // something using i variable
   }
   // i can use i here but not j
}
```

to learn more look up Scope in C [https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_scope_rules.htm#:~:text=A%20scope%20in%20any%20programming,which%20is%20called%20local%20variables](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_scope_rules.htm#:%7E:text=A%20scope%20in%20any%20programming,which%20is%20called%20local%20variables).

Answer (score 2):

The following code will be an infinite loop until limit reached (the value i will keep increasing, if you have replaced var2 with i )

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int var=10;
    for (int i = 0; i < var; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j < i; i++)
    {
     printf("test %d", i );    
    
    }
    
}
```